# Preg_replace ': and numbers'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've the following problem.

In Wordpress I'm outputting the categories on the website. In this output they give the following value:

```
Category:1
```

Now I have the following code which removes the one:

```
$resultx = " " . rgar( $entry, '49' ) ."";
$resultx_ = preg_replace('/\d/' , '', $resultx );
```

But when I'm adding the following rule:

```
$resultx_ = preg_replace('/:/' , '', $resultx );
```

it removes the `:` and leaves the `1`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You are overriding the initial $resultx_ without considering the previous result set o it. Which is why it still have the number. $resultx was never changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to strip off the final colon and number, then use this:

```
$resultx = "Category:1";
$resultx = preg_replace('/:\d*$/' , '', $resultx );
echo $resultx;

Category
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_` on the haystack of the second `preg_replace` call is missing so you go back to the original string and bypass the number replacement. To correct this do:

```
$resultx = 'Category:1';
$resultx_ = preg_replace('/\d/' , '', $resultx);
$resultx_ = preg_replace('/:/' , '', $resultx_);
```

but you can do a `:` and number replacement all in one regex:

```
$resultx_ = preg_replace('/[:\d]*/' , '', $resultx);
```

You also could replace numbers and colons with `str_replace`:

```
$resultx_ = str_replace(array_merge(range(0,9), array(':')), '', $resultx);
```

or `rtrim` if you only want them replaced from the end.

```
$resultx_ = rtrim($resultx, implode(range(0,9)) . ':');
```

If the pattern is exactly `:` then number though use the [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51965497/3783243) regex.